# Where is the XACT documentation?

Tags: xna

All the links here are broken:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172314.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XACT can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827592.aspx)

Hope it helps

Comment: That's the API reference, not the Authoring Tool documentation linked to in the question.

Answer (score 5):

The links are not broken, or are not any longer anyway - they redirect to the *Where is the DirectX SDK?* page which tells us that the XACT Authoring Tool is no longer supported, that's why that part of the documentation is removed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee663275.aspx

> Where is the DirectX SDK?
>
> The Xbox Audio Cross Platform Tool (XACT) is no longer supported for
> use on Windows.

As AbstractChaos answered, the XACT API reference is still there though but that in turn links to the removed documentation for the tool that is posted in the question. Hence, it's removed.

> For detailed information about how to author audio using the XACT
> tool, including information about categories, variables, and other
> advanced features, see **(redirected to discontinued support statement)**.

Comment: and that link leads to DirectX SDK which has nothing to with XACT. Irrespective of whether it is supported or not it still works and is used! One does throw away the documentation of ones operating system for example because the manufacturer is no longer supporting it!

Comment: I think it is till supported - see AbstractChaos's answer - imagine all the people who reached the same conclusion as you - which i dont blame you for

Comment: No, my interpretation is that the authoring tool you asked for documentation for is not supported anymore. However, the XACT API that AbstractChaos links to is - that's two very different things and I see nothing about advanced tool usage in that link. However, discontinuing the tool support could be interpreted as yet another nail in XNAs coffin.

Comment: its no longer developes but works fine and will be used for a long time to come. I agree I still cannot find the advanced documentation. XNA is not going anywhere - it is speculation it is dying - i speculate its going from strength to strength

Answer (score 5):

The wayback machine appears to have preserved a copy of at least some of the documentation:

http://web.archive.org/web/20080514084356/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172314.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can download full MSDN Library for Visual Studio from the Microsoft website. But I think you need the same version of Visual Studio as is the version of the downloadable MSDN to be able to view it. **[Here is a link to download page of MSDN Library for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20955)**, that should contain the information you are looking for. Unfortunately I don't own the MS Visual Studio 2008, so I can't make sure.

Comment: I installed VS2008 today, sadly that MSDN download didn't contain the XACT documentation :(